# Flask form validation - CSRF token middleware

Tags: python, html, flask

I have an html form, and I would like to insure that all submissions come from my website. I think I have seen people using a key for this (I believe this happens in Django?), and might have some ideas on how to go with that. Is there any standard way to do this in Flask?

**Edit:**
Now I know I'm talking about CSRF token middleware. Again, is there any standard way of doing this in Flask? How can I store the key on the server side?

Comment: Are u talking about CSRF token middleware

Comment: Yes! That's what I mean. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In flask you can do CSRF protection using `Flask-SeaSurf`.There are other methods also but it is straight forward.

To start Just do `pip install flask-seasurf` and you are ready

```
import Flask
from flask_seasurf import SeaSurf

app = Flask(__name__)
csrf = SeaSurf(app)
```

```
<form method="POST">
    ...
    <input type="hidden" name="_csrf_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
</form>
```

```
@csrf.exempt
@app.route('/exempt_view', methods=['POST'])
def exempt_view():
    '''This view is exempted from CSRF validation.'''
    return 'foobar'
```

For more information you can visit [official website](https://flask-seasurf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)

Please mark this as answer if this solves you problem.